# Relaunch application from CoreBlutooth - didUpdateValueForCharacteristic function

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

How can I reopen my application from didUpdateValueForCharacteristic function. I want to go back to the app from SpringBoard or any other app that is running in the background?

I have an iTag device so every time I tap on it invokes that method.

```
/**

 - parameter peripheral:     The periphreal which call the method
 - parameter characteristic: The characteristic with the new value
 - parameter error:          The error message
 */
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    print("Bluetooth Manager --> didUpdateValueForCharacteristic")
    print("Bluetooth Manager (Service)--> \(characteristic.service)")


    print("-------------------------------")
    if error != nil {
        print("Bluetooth Manager --> Failed to read value for the characteristic. Error:\(error!.localizedDescription)")
        delegate?.didFailToReadValueForCharacteristic?(error!)
        return
    }
    delegate?.didReadValueForCharacteristic?(characteristic)

}
```

Comment: You mean you want to programatically move your app from the background to the foreground? That's not possible.

Comment: Yes I wanted that, how can I make a phone call from the background state? Xcode project only responsible to the app space and not SpringBoard and stuff?

Comment: You should seriously look into what restrictions do iOS apps have and what is possible in the world of these restrictions. You can't make phone calls from third party apps at all.

Comment: Yes I know , I am confused with what I can do and not because I have jailbroken device. Can I make a notification that handles that phone call?

Answer (score 0):

//Yes you can using url schema
//Setup url schema for you app the

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
```

//Where url will be url for you app.
//You can also launch any another app using url schema

Comment: Thanks , I try that but phone call is done only in the app space . I also want to make a phone call from that iTag sensor BLE physical click in background.

Comment: use a button for phonecall and send action to that button when you want to make phone call

Comment: Why action and not a function? Anyway , it makes a phone call only when I tap the device **while in the app**. Is it possible at all to make a phone call / create a notification , when I am not in the app? Maybe using Appdelegate.